# how to get hosted ip and country name of a domain using php

Tags: php, ip, geoip

In my application after entering the domain name in a text field I want to auto populate the domain's IP and Country.

Comment: to use geoip_country_name_by_name()  you need the PECL extension, have a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php

Comment: Note that that's not necessarily possible by definition. Do you have any idea how many servers there are worldwide for google.com?

Comment: @Zan, if i want to get country name what code should i add to my file and what are necessary files

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [**`gethostbyname()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) (returns a single IP) and [**`gethostbynamel()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) gives you a list of IP addresses associated with the hostname.

Here's an example.

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

Regarding grabbing country information, you need a 3rd party solution.

Comment: how can i solve the error
    
    Call to undefined function geoip_country_name_by_name()

Comment: @SekharSeerapu, seems like you haven't included the libraries of geoip.

Comment: yes..help me in this .how can i include them @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: @SekharSeerapu, you need to install the PECL extension in PHP. It will  work fine after you do that. Here's the link http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php

Comment: @SekharSeerapu, Why you keep switching your mind ? Did you try installing PECL ? That will solve your issue. If you face anything let us know we are here to help.

Comment: hey i already downloaded the files and added to my folder.It gives me the IP address but not country..I don,t know what is the problem.Please help me